# Visual studio Templates or Code snippets to create classes and interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, code-snippets, visual-studio-2019

I am writing some Unit Tests and would like to create a Template/Code Snippet (Not sure what the exact terminology is in Visual studio). In simple terms i would like to create some boiler plate code which I can re-use.

i.e., 
User will enter a Name of the class and use it to create a Interface, classes and some method definitions.

e.g, If a user enters VATRate

IVATRate will be created in xyz.Common.Interfaces

VATRateRepository will be created in xyz.BusinessLayer

VATRateRepositoryTests will be created in xyz.BusinessLayer.Tests

Methods in VATRateREpositoryTests will be defined
InsertVATRate_ShouldInsertNewRecord_WhenVatRateDoesNotExist
UpsertVATRate_ShouldUpdateRecord_WhenRecordExist
GetAllVATRate_ReadsAllRecords

etc..

Comment: Good to know that you are writing unit tests. What is your question?

Comment: @Sunil - Thanks for your comment. I just want to create some boiler plate code. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate it with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension. The code for a command in C# will look like this:

References: Microsoft.VisualBasic

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        string className = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Class name", "Create tests",
                    "VATRate", -1, -1);
        EnvDTE.ProjectItem f = DTE.ItemOperations.AddNewItem("Visual C# Items\\Code\\Class", className + "RepositoryTests.cs");
        EnvDTE.CodeClass c = FirstClass(FirstNamespace(f.FileCodeModel.CodeElements).Children);
        c.AddFunction("Insert" + className, vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction, vsCMTypeRef.vsCMTypeRefVoid);
    }

    private EnvDTE.CodeNamespace FirstNamespace(EnvDTE.CodeElements elements)
    {
        foreach(EnvDTE.CodeElement c in elements)
        {
            if(c is EnvDTE.CodeNamespace)
            return c as EnvDTE.CodeNamespace;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private EnvDTE.CodeClass FirstClass(EnvDTE.CodeElements elements)
    {
        foreach (EnvDTE.CodeElement c in elements)
        {
            if (c is EnvDTE.CodeClass)
                return c as EnvDTE.CodeClass;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you select a project in your solution and run the command from the VCmd menu, it will create the following file:

[image]